# Is there a way to use getattr to call dynamic functions without using __import__?

Tags: python

I am using getattr to call functions at runtime. There are many functions and they live in a few separate files. I am currently doing this the following way:

Say the functions live in PACKAGE/functions_*.py

The actual call is done in a class method:

```
class SomeClass(object):
    ...

    def call(self, **kwargs):
        function_name = '{}_{}'.format(self.parms['prefix'], self.parms['name'])
        file_name =  self.parms['prefix']
        mod_name = 'PACKAGE.{}'.format(file_name)
        module = __import__(mod_name, globals(), locals(), [file_name,])
        return getattr(module, function_name)(**kwargs)
```

The above code works fine, but it appears overly complex to me, also it looks like every time this method is called it has to open the PACKAGE/function_*.py file (because there is no import statement for it).

Because this method gets executed thousands of times, I don't want the code to be unnecessarily inefficient.

**Question**: Is there a better/more efficient way to do this? Or is my concern about the inefficiency of repeated file opening unfounded?

Note: It appeared cleaner to me to first import all PACKAGE.function_x.py files (there are not many), but then I could not work out how to use the getattr (module) object to refer to these imports.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider a plugin system instead.

Comment: Not sure about `__import__`, but I would bet that it sticks imported modules in to `sys.modules` just like `import` and `importlib.import_module`.  I'm not sure if it does it implicitly, but you can always explicitly check if the module is in `sys.modules` before doing the import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you cache the imported functions? E.g. let your class contain a `_cached_func` dictionary:

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._cached_func = {}

    def call(self, **kwargs):
        function_name = '{}_{}'.format(self.parms['prefix'], self.parms['name'])

        try:
            func = self._cached_func[function_name]
        except KeyError:            
            file_name =  self.parms['prefix']
            mod_name = 'PACKAGE.{}'.format(file_name)
            module = __import__(mod_name, globals(), locals(), [file_name,])
            func = getattr(module, function_name)
            self._cached_func[function_name] = func

        return func(**kwargs)
```

Comment: This is maybe not the answer I was looking for when I asked the question, but now I am thinking it is even better.